# Regex to allow 0 to 5 hyphens within a 10 - 15 numeric character string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex for the following requirements:

1. 10 numerical characters minimum
2. 15 numerical characters maximum
3. Allow 0 to 5 hyphens, anywhere within string

I have this following regex, but it exceeds the 15 numerical character requirement if there aren't any hyphens:

```
/^([0-9]{10,15}|(?=[-]*)[0-9-]{11,19})$/
```

Thanks.

Comment: So, just to make sure I understand, this could potentially be a total of 20 characters.  15 digits + 5 hyphens, right?

Comment: What language is this for (php, javascript, c#?). I don't know a way to limit number of characters within, but have an alternate solution (just want to write it in a language you can use)

Comment: this is a complex regex that no one will understand with out asking you when they run into it.  you could execute two simple regexs and validate your requirement.  That would be more readable and more maintainable later.

Answer (score 3):

This regex will check for 0 to 5 hyphens and 10 to 15 digits. Any other characters are allowed.

```
^(?=[^-]*(-[^-]*){0,5}$)(?=\D*(\d\D*){10,15}$).*$
```

And this only allows digits and hyphens:

```
^(?=\d*(-\d*){0,5}$)(?=-*(\d-*){10,15}$).*$
```

[Test it.](http://rubular.com/r/pmNqOdYzGO)

Comment: For some strange reason (this should work, as far as I can see), this fails in [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/pQT5Xfwb20) without adding a `[^-]*` before the first `$`; [as you can see](http://www.rubular.com/r/o3CoyNsCbK), that works, although it shouldn't (?) be necessary.  Thoughts?

Comment: Fixed the failing if there are no hyphens. I noticed it too.

Comment: @Antal S-Z It **is** necessary because the lookahead is from `^` to `$` and if no hyphens are present then it has nothing else to match the string. This is why the `\d*` (or `[^-]*` is needed).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for (the 2nd one which allows only digits and hyphens).  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this can't be accomplished purely with one regex.

Here's an example using Python 2.6 without regular expressions (assumes input is only digits and hyphens):

```
input = "123-45678----9"
digitCount = len(input.translate(None, '-'))
hyphenCount = len(input.translate(None, '0123456789'))
if digitCount >= 0 and digitCount <= 15 and hyphenCount >= 0 and hyphenCount <= 5:
    print "Yay!"
```